# Hiding Minimize Maximize button on WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to Hide/Disable Minimize and Maximize button on WPF window.

I have tried using WinAPI

I added following class in my code base

```cs
internal static class WindowExtensions
{
    // from winuser.h
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16,
        WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000,
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern private static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    extern private static int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int value);

    internal static void HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(this Window window)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        var currentStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(currentStyle & -65537 & -131073));
    }
}
```

then I tried to call the HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons method on SourceInitialised method of that window.

This is the only solution I found on Internet.

Can anyone Suggest any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to hide the entire title bar with

```
<Window 
    WindowStyle="None"
```

and create the "program closing button" with a custom button if you need it

Comment: This is not necessary. Setting the WindowStyle to *ToolWindow* or the ResizeMode to *NoResize* will achieve this without the need for a custom closing button.

Comment: @KostasK. You are right, ResizeMode to "NoResize" is better